# python memory error for kmeans in scikit-learn

Tags: python, c++, scikit-learn, k-means

I am running this [Selecting the number of clusters](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_kmeans_silhouette_analysis.html#example-cluster-plot-kmeans-silhouette-analysis-py) example of `scikit-learn` in `python`. the example gets several samples with 2 features and finds best k for `kmeans` clustering.

In my case I have samples with 3 features. they are `3 dimensional coordinates` indeed. so, in the code I just change the input to my samples and the rest remains same. number of my sample points are very big maybe more than 10,000 points.

when I input all my data I got memory error (I have 16GB of RAM and all of it got full). But when I put half of my data it doesn't give the error. Although the error shows by ipython notebook for silhouette function but I am pretty sure it happens in kmeans and it doesn't perform clustering and jumps to this error suddenly.

With same amount of data I did kmeans clustering in `C++` and it was totally fine and fast without any problem.
is there any idea how can I resolve this problem? 
this is the error I got

```
         MemoryError              Traceback (most recent call last)
        <ipython-input-4-ed4b060ccea1> in <module>()
 41     # This gives a perspective into the density and separation of the formed
 42     # clusters
---> 43     silhouette_avg = silhouette_score(X, cluster_labels)
 44     print("For n_clusters =", n_clusters,
 45           "The average silhouette_score is :", silhouette_avg)

/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/cluster/unsupervised.pyc in silhouette_score(X, labels, metric, sample_size, random_state, **kwds)
 82         else:
 83             X, labels = X[indices], labels[indices]
---> 84     return np.mean(silhouette_samples(X, labels, metric=metric, **kwds))
 85 
 86 

  /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/cluster/unsupervised.pyc in silhouette_samples(X, labels, metric, **kwds)
141 
142     """
 --> 143     distances = pairwise_distances(X, metric=metric, **kwds)
144     n = labels.shape[0]
145     A = np.array([_intra_cluster_distance(distances[i], labels, i)

 /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/pairwise.pyc in pairwise_distances(X, Y, metric, n_jobs, **kwds)
649         func = pairwise_distance_functions[metric]
650         if n_jobs == 1:
--> 651             return func(X, Y, **kwds)
652         else:
653             return _parallel_pairwise(X, Y, func, n_jobs, **kwds)

 /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/pairwise.pyc in euclidean_distances(X, Y, Y_norm_squared, squared)
181         distances.flat[::distances.shape[0] + 1] = 0.0
182 
--> 183     return distances if squared else np.sqrt(distances)
184 
185 

MemoryError:
```

Comment: how do you input your data? maybe it could be generated lazily.

Comment: like this mypath =/Desktop/trainingFiles/'
onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f))]
resulted_trajectories = []
for i in range(6,len(onlyfiles)):
  fname = onlyfiles[i]
    filepath = mypath + fname
    f = open(filepath, 'r')
    t = f.read().split('\n')
    for line in t:
        if line:
            ll = [float(x) for x in line.split(',')]
            resulted_trajectories.append(ll)
all_Trajectories = np.array(resulted_trajectories)
print(all_Trajectories)
X = all_Trajectories
range_n_clusters = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

Comment: then I use X as input

Answer (score 2):

It's *not* k-means which runs out of memory.

But the Silhouette evaluation index needs *quadratic* distance computations, and apparently sklearn tries to do this by computing a *distance matrix*. Most likely, it will even need multiple copies of it.

Now, do the math yourself. Most implementations run out of memory at around 64k instances when trying to compute a full distance matrix.

Thus, remove the call to silhouette.

Comment: yes you are right, problem is not with kmeans because when I remove sillouette part it works. what is the solution ? I need sillouette anyway, I have around 10000 instance and each has 3 features. any idea ?

Comment: Implement silhouette yourself, and try hard to conserve memory. 10000 is doable with 400MB of RAM.

Comment: now i see the size it is around 60,000  3D instances, there is a parameter `sample size` that make sillouette use a sample of all instances to calculate the distance matrix. do you think how much sample size is enough for this size of data ?

Comment: 60k is still feasible, with 10GB of RAM in a good implementation. I cannot recommend sample sizes gor silhouette - I don't use this heuristic, it is too often misleading IMHO. Never trust a "quality" number.